# Contribution to growth

Tags: subgroup-growth

Hope you´re well! I need some help! Is this formula ok? I want to calculate the contribution to growth and I have the following formula.

Contribution to Growth = (This year’s sales for my brand – Last year’s sales for my brand) / Change in volume for category

Contribution Growth Index = (Change vs.YAG in absolute dollars for my item divided into change vs.YAG in absolute dollars for the category is my contribution to growth. Take that and divide it by dollar share YAG x 100)

Is it correct to write (this year’s sales USD for my brand - last year’s sales for my brand USD) divided (Total sales this year USD - Total sales last year USD)?

Thanks in advance!